# Were some of the NPCs in 'Waterdeep: Dragon Heist' player characters at some point?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, npc, history-of-gaming, waterdeep-dragon-heist

The **Waterdeep: Dragon Heist** adventure has some rather colorful NPCs that, as part of their backstory, were adventurers exploring the Undermountain in the past. Among them are:

- *Durnan*, the propietor of the Yawning Portal
- *Mirt*, the moneylender, a former rogue

Were these characters (or others) originally player characters in the original Undermountain campaign?

Comment: I rolled back an edit that largely changed the wording of the title, and added a superfluous tag (which, if it were in somebody's ignored tags would prevent them seeing this question). OP, if you prefer the edit before mine please rollback my rollback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mirt, and most Forgotten Realms characters (as opposed to Greyhawk and Dragonlance), are [original characters for novels](https://www.enworld.org/threads/ed-greenwood-the-origins-of-mirt-the-moneylender.666767/), not D&D games. [Ed Greenwood](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ed_Greenwood) is the original designer of the setting, and penned a lot of the most well-known and well-fleshed-out characters. See also: this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Forgotten_Realms/comments/qt8dy7/comment/hkhzwcz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) thread (although I haven't vetted the information contained there).

There may be more information in his [edition-neutral Forgotten Realms sourcebook](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/166568/Ed-Greenwood-Presents-Elminsters-Forgotten-Realms) (but I don't own it, and have no affiliation, just linking to it for interest) – or in one of the various [Q&A threads](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=1901) he has been active in.

Comment: Fascinating that the characters of Mirt and Durnan pre-date role playing games, I'd never expected that. Thank you.

Comment: I'd doubt the reliability of the reddit thread though: Mordenkainen was *not* a DM-run NPC, he was Gary's (second I think) PC, played honestly in many adventures that Rob Kuntz ran for Gary in his El Raja Key dungeon, including the famous one with the firebreathing Steel Golem that made it into a module. He recounted these stories himself, all of this is quite well documented.

Comment: I felt like it went without saying to take a reddit link with a grain of salt, but I can mention it more specifically.